Google Home Notification
I want to create a script that fetches some data from an external API. The data contains prayer times. I want to send a broadcast to my Google Home mini 15 minutes before every prayer time.
I wanted to do it via webhooks, and tried using IFTTT and Zapier to send the notification to Google home, but they don't support broadcasting on google home.
Any ideas?
Also preferably, I would like to pull and schedule notifications all at once, for a year in advance, so I don't have to have a live server all the time - not sure how doable this is.

Right now there is no way to integrate automations directly into 3rd party services . However, you can implement a virtual device and change the code in a way which changes the state of the device in a way that corresponds to your automation .
You can make use of the following documentation for creating a virtual device and making use in creating automation.
